# Cannot navigate to recent projects in emacs dashboard: "Symbol's function definition is void: nil" error

Tags: debugging, projectile, dashboard

Recently, I have not been able to open any of my recent projects that show up on the dashboard screen (package `emacs-dashboard`). If I move my cursor over one of the projects and press enter nothing happens, and I get the message `Symbol's function definition is void: nil`.

It was working a couple of weeks ago, but I'm not really sure what I did to break it. I'm not sure if it was updating the packages or if I installed something new that broke it.

Can this be fixed?

EDIT: Output from debugger

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function nil)
  nil("[.emacs.d] Find file: " (".cache/treemacs-persist" ".lsp-session-v1"  "package-files here"...))
  projectile-completing-read("Find file: " (".cache/treemacs-persist" ".lsp-session-v1" "package files here"...))
  projectile--find-file(nil)
  projectile-find-file()
  projectile-switch-project-by-name("~/.emacs.d/")
  funcall(projectile-switch-project-by-name "~/.emacs.d/")
  (lambda (&rest ignore) (funcall (dashboard-projects-backend-switch-function) (dashboard-expand-path-alist "0|~/.emacs.d/" dashboard-projects-alist)))((item :tag "~/.emacs.d/" :action (lambda (&rest ignore) (funcall (dashboard-projects-backend-switch-function) (dashboard-expand-path-alist "0|~/.emacs.d/" dashboard-projects-alist))) :button-face dashboard-items-face :mouse-face highlight :button-prefix "" :button-suffix "" :format "%[%t%]" :button-overlay #<overlay from 499 to 510 in *dashboard*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 499 in *dashboard*> :to #<marker at 510 in *dashboard*>) nil)
  widget-apply((item :tag "~/.emacs.d/" :action (lambda (&rest ignore) (funcall (dashboard-projects-backend-switch-function) (dashboard-expand-path-alist "0|~/.emacs.d/" dashboard-projects-alist))) :button-face dashboard-items-face :mouse-face highlight :button-prefix "" :button-suffix "" :format "%[%t%]" :button-overlay #<overlay from 499 to 510 in *dashboard*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 499 in *dashboard*> :to #<marker at 510 in *dashboard*>) :action nil)
  widget-apply-action((item :tag "~/.emacs.d/" :action (lambda (&rest ignore) (funcall (dashboard-projects-backend-switch-function) (dashboard-expand-path-alist "0|~/.emacs.d/" dashboard-projects-alist))) :button-face dashboard-items-face :mouse-face highlight :button-prefix "" :button-suffix "" :format "%[%t%]" :button-overlay #<overlay from 499 to 510 in *dashboard*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 499 in *dashboard*> :to #<marker at 510 in *dashboard*>) nil)
  widget-button-press(503)
  dashboard-return()
  funcall-interactively(dashboard-return)
  call-interactively(dashboard-return nil nil)
  command-execute(dashboard-return)
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Start by setting variable `debug-on-error` to `t`. That will show you a backtrace, where you can see where the error is raised. Posting that additional info here might help others help you.

Comment: Thanks. Debug info added.